# is there a way to make this if-function not case sensitive

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement

```
name=str(input(f"Enter your name: "))

if name=="Alice" or name=="Thabo":
    print(f"Hello, {name}")
```

I want the code to display "Hello Alice" / "Hello Thabo" in a format of the first letter being capitalized, even if the user enters the name in lower case, e.g. alice/thabo
I tried using `.upper` functions but that isn't working.

Comment: `if name.lower() in ['alice', 'thabo']: print(f'Hello {name.title()}')`

Comment: Or `if name.casefold() in ['alice', 'thabo']` ;)